# Unity PropertyAttribute, interfering with other PropertyAttributes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I have an Attribute

```
public class LockAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }
```

with a custom drawer script

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(LockAttribute))]
public class LockAttributePropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer 
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(Application.isPlaying);
        _= EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
    }
}
```

it's purpose is to disable the inspector field when the application is playing.

If I use it in this order

```
[SerializeField,Range(0,100),Lock] private int m_Resolution;
```

the field never disables, and when I swap the `Range` and `Lock` attributes, the `Range` attribute has no effect.

Is there a way to have both attributes take effect?

I attempted using

```
Base.OnGUI(position, property, label);
```

instead of

```
EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label);
```

but doing so resulting in `No GUI Implmented` appearing over my fields`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a "bug" in Unity 2020.3.

It works for me if I simply invert the order (Unity 2021.2.2f1):

```
[SerializeField] 
[Lock]
[Range(0, 100)]
private int m_Resolution;
```

Alternatively you can also add the `order` parameter like

```
[SerializeField] 
[Range(0, 100, order = 1)]
[Lock(order = 0)]
private int m_Resolution;
```

though I would prefer to rather simply have them in the correct order right away ^^

[image]

---

My general Guess: The reason is that in this case you first add the disabled group, then let the `PropertyField` handle any other drawers added later that internally might not be using `PropertyField` but rather direct value drawers.
If you have the `Range` first, however, it already overwrites the drawer completely with direct value fields (the slider) and doesn't further forward the draw call via a `PropertyField` so no later attribute drawers are handled anymore.

---

So long story short: Unfortunately multiple attributes are always quite tricky and most of them are not able to be combined or at least like in this case the order matters a lot!

For example even though the `[Min]` attributes on first glance doesn't change the appearance of an `int` field, still your `[Lock]` needs to go first, otherwise it is ignored.

And there is e.g. no way at all to combine `[Range]` and `[Min]` regardless the order.

=> For those cases you would need to go and write a new combined attribute and drawer yourself!

Comment: Perhaps the problem was resolved somewhere between our two versions as I am using 2020.3.21f1

Comment: @RWolfe just confirmed that, yes! Seems to be a "bug" then. It is also not working for me in Unity `2020.3.22f1`!